# how to use javascript to simulate click on link where href is php

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Google Chrome Extension.  I need to use javascript to simulate a click on this link: `<a href="/logout.php /a>` so I can log out.  How can I get this done?

No JQuery please, I haven't learned it yet.

Comment: a) That's very invalid HTML b) Whatever is behind the link doesn't matter at all, PHP is of no concern here.

Answer (score 3):

Main function will create any event:

```
   function ShowOperationMessage(obj, evt) {
        var fireOnThis = obj;
        if (document.createEvent) {
            var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evObj.initEvent(evt, true, false);
            fireOnThis.dispatchEvent(evObj);
        } else if (document.createEventObject) {
            fireOnThis.fireEvent('on' + evt);
        }
    }
```

Now call the function:

```
 ShowOperationMessage(document.getElementById("linkID"), "click");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is for an extension, you could submit an XHR request to the server `/logout.php` rather than simulate a click.

But simulating a mouse click is rather simple, I use the following code in many of my extensions:

```
function simulateClick(element) {
  if (!element) return;
  var dispatchEvent = function (elt, name) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent(name, true, true);
    elt.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
  };
  dispatchEvent(element, 'mouseover');
  dispatchEvent(element, 'mousedown');
  dispatchEvent(element, 'click');
  dispatchEvent(element, 'mouseup');
};
```